getting GoogleAuthError while following a langchain tutorial
I am trying to follow an "official"  langchain tutorial How to do question answering over CSVs using llm model = gemini-1.5-flash   but my code is failing anyways.   I am writing/running the code in Jupyter notebook.
Before I executed the code, I went to my Google Cloud account and created an API key and named it as "GOOGLE_API_KEY" as shown below, as the tutorial code requires it.

I had no problem with running the code from the tutorial with  Jupyter notebook until it got stuck when it executed the getpass() logic. I did a workaround by replacing the getpass with  using load_dotenv()  as shown below.
 #   SET UP GCP Credentials 
 #   Create GOOGLE_API_KEY to access the llm model USING Google Cloud console

from dotenv import load_dotenv
# import getpass
import os

# run load_dotenv() to get the GOOGLE_API_KEY value from the .env file 
load_dotenv()
os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY")

I created an .env  file containing the  GOOGLE_API_KEY=<value> line which the dotenv_load_env() was able to read successfully.
But unfortunately, I encountered an error  when executing the llm assignment statement.
from langchain_google_vertexai import ChatVertexAI

llm = ChatVertexAI(model="gemini-1.5-flash")

This is the error that I received:

The error shows GoogleAuthError with  exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS).  But the langchain tutorial code  does not require it.
Helpful input(s) from experienced stackoverflowers is much appreciated.

I looked up the langchain documentation and found  that I actually do NOT need the GOOGLE_API_KEY -  all I need is to generate and download the credentials file (JSON file type) for the service account associated with my GCP project (please follow this Youtube link on how to do this from the GCP Console), then updated the code to create the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable and set its value to the path of the generated file - I chose to rename the credentials file to my_account_credetials.json:
#   SET UP GCP Credentials:  create a credentials JSON file for your service account
#   and point the file path to the environment variable named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./my_account_credentials.json"

After providing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file the  LLM assignment statement finally ran successfully.
